# Why can't I see the layout preview in Android Studio but instead I see a 'cross' sign and am not able to add any elements?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Screenshot of what appears on clicking layout and selecting the design tab.
[image]

I tried installing android studio thrice but each time I see the same 'cross' sign instead of a Hello World on the phone.

Comment: What does your xml show?

Comment: Click 'Show Log in Explorer' and post your log

Comment: Your gradle sync failed. See what happened with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to build.gradle(Module:app) file check your minSdkVersion make it 17 and above
and sync your gradle. in my case it solve.

Answer (score 1):

Go to file menu -> invalidate caches/restart -> invalidate and restart

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle Project Sync failed because Gradle wasn't installed properly and Android Studio wouldn't install or complete the incomplete installation. So I manually reinstalled Gradle and followed the steps given on this link and the preview came back. Thanks for for helping anyways. Cheers!
[Install Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/)

Answer (score 0):

your view is zoomed at 1000% which makes it go out of bounds so just zoom in or make to 50 to 70 % and it will be visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've met this issue, try sync gradle [image]